# Area under curves functional analysis question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Consider the functions defined inplicitly by te equation $y^{3}-3y+x=0$ on various intervals in the real line . If $x\in(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)$ the equation implicitly defines a unique real valued differentiable function $y=f(x)$ . if $x\in (-2,2)$, the equation implicitly defines a unique real valued differentiable function $y=g(x)$ satisfying $g(0)=0$.

Q1) If $f(-10\sqrt{2}) =2\sqrt{2}$ , then $f''(-10\sqrt{2})$ = ?

Q2) $\int^{1}_{-1}g'(x)dx$ =

Q3) The area of the region bounded by the curve $y=f(x)$, the x-axis and the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$ where $-\infty<a<b<-2$, ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

**Q1)**
$$f(x)^3-3f(x)-x=0\implies (f(x)^3-3f(x)+x)'=0\implies(f(x)^3-3f(x)+x)''=0 $$

**Q2)** You can find $g'$ by solving the Cauchy problem $$\begin{cases}(g(x)^3-3g(x)+x)'=0\\g(0)=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: What about the intervals , any significance ?

Comment: I didn't made the exercice, but I think it will influence the existence of the solution of the Cauchy-problem (and may be also influence the value of $f''(-10\sqrt 2)$ in Q1) in the case where you also have to solve an EDO).

Comment: I don't think we need to use it anywhere , questions seem fairly in the appropriate domains

Comment: also i didn't quite get how to solve the second question ,do i just integrate simply , how do i introduce $f(x)$ in it .Also could you please suggest me some good links to learn about cauchy's integration rule

Comment: I meant the third question

Comment: Ok, then I think that the interval allow to write $y$ as $y=f(x)$ (theorem of implicit function). For Q3) I don't know... sorry ! Moreover, 2nd line of your original post, is it really $x\in (-\infty ,2)\cup (2,\infty )$ ? or did you want to mean $(-\infty ,-2)\cup(2,\infty )$ ?

Comment: okay no problem btw is the second question answer $2g(1)$ because $g'(x)$ seems to be even

Comment: idk , thats whats been given on my question paper,

Comment: Wait i will show you the options to help get you the clue

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z5JB1.jpg

Comment: Ok, then an integration by part gives the answer $(A)$.

Comment: how , what did you integrate

Comment: By part,$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=[xf(x)]_a^b-\int_a^b xf'(x)dx.$$ Since $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{3(f^2(x)-1)} $, you got your result.

Answer (score 2):

$(1)\;\;$ Given $$y^3-3y+x=0\;,...........(1)$$ Now Differentiate both side w. r to $x\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle 3y^2\cdot y'-3y'+1=0....................(2)\Rightarrow y'=\frac{1}{3-3y^2}\;,$$ Where $$\displaystyle y=f(x)\;\;, y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)\;\;,y''=f''(x)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Now Given $\displaystyle y=f\left(-10\sqrt{2}\right)=2\sqrt{2}.$

So we get $$\displaystyle y' = \frac{1}{3-3y^2}=\frac{1}{3-3(2\sqrt{2})^2} = -\frac{1}{21}$$

Now Again Differentiate $(2)\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle 3y^2\cdot y''+y'\cdot 6yy'-3y''=0\Rightarrow 6y(y')^2+3y^2y''-3y''=0$$

Now put $\displaystyle y = 2\sqrt{2}$ and $\displaystyle y'=-\frac{1}{21}\;,$ We get $\displaystyle y''= \frac{2y(y')^2}{1-3y^2}=-\frac{6\cdot 2\sqrt{2}}{(21)^3} = -\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{243\times9}$

So we get $\displaystyle f''\left(-10\sqrt{2}\right) = -\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{243\times 9}$

$(2)\;\;$ We have $$\displaystyle g'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3[1-(f(x))^2]}$$ (Even function)

So $$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} g'(x) = 2\int_{0}^{1}g'(x)dx = 2\left[g(x)\right]_{0}^{1} = 2[g(1)-g(0)] = 2g(0)\;\;,$$ bcz given $g(0)=0$

$(3)\;\;$ The Required Area $$\displaystyle = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cdot 1 dx = \left[x\cdot f(x)\right]_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}xf'(x)dx$$

$$\displaystyle =bf(b)-af(a)+\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x}{3\left[(f(x))^2-1\right]}dx$$

Bcz from equation no. $(2)\;,$ We have $\displaystyle y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3-3y^2}$

Comment: Welcome  Sujith Zis